# Execute multiple sql scripts in order using web deploy

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, webdeploy

I am using SSDT project to keep my current schema.
I have some scripts that I need to run during deployment of sql database.

How can I setup scripts to execute in order as on picture below?

Currently my deploy fails when I have added publish data into post deploy, which means that steps 1,2 did not execute as I hoped.

See order I need to execute those below:

[image: Web publish question]

Comment: can you make one script that calls all the other scripts in the proper order?

Comment: @Randy the issue is auto schema update. If I had only predeployment and post deployment I have no issue.